# What percentage of new users come from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, users, new-users

I'm here because of stack overflow.  I wonder how many of our first time questions come from people who have other accounts on SE?

Comment: I don't have access to that info, but I'll try and see if a dev can dig that up. I'd guess that the number will be upwards of 50-60%. We had quite a few non-SO/trilogy affiliated users in the early days (some still around) and the ones that stood out the most are [Mancuniensis](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/136/mancuniensis) and [Shanna](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/133/shanna). Both of them haven't been around in a long time (with Shanna not visiting since the first week of public beta!). I'd clump Mike Perry in there too, but he did hint that he was on SO earlier...

Comment: Thanks, just doing what I do best. Asking good questions...

Answer (score 6):

Here's your info, thanks to [Rebecca Chernoff](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/users/34/rebecca-chernoff):

```
1247 (non-employee) users on Gardening
1122 registered users
1030 users have an account on SO or SU or SF
1003 users had SO/SU/SF before Gardening
```

I didn't ask for users who had accounts on SE 2.0 sites prior to Gardening, but as you can see from the above, that number is going to be pretty tiny.

Comment: If I understand correctly then about eighty percent of users on Gardening are users of other SE forums.

Comment: What about people like me, who won't be included in the 'other SE users' stats - I'd never heard of Stack Exchange, but was looking for a less 'social' gardening site - my son's a mobile computer programmer, he told me about this, wouldn't have known otherwise.

Comment: It's February of 2016. Is anyone willing to add a new answer based on more recent information? That would be great, thanks!

Comment: @Bamboo  I would imagine you would fall under the 'registered users' number since you are a registered user.

Comment: @Citizen - yea, I certainly do now, I belong to 4 or 5 other parts of SE apart from G & L

Comment: I definitely do.